# How to replace the last string character with a new string in Perl

Tags: perl, substr

I am iterating an excel sheet in one column B. If a cell contains a `"`, then replace it with `Inches`. However, when using the substr function, `$newval` remains blank. In the test run both `$cell` and `$ind` contain the right values. I got no errors and no warnings.

Why is `$newval` blank? I found this substr-example online and can't seem to figure out what I am doing differently:

> An alternative to using substr as an lvalue is to specify the replacement string as the 4th argument. This allows you to replace parts of the EXPR and return what was there before in one operation, just as you can with splice.

```
    my $s = "The black cat climbed the green tree";
    my $z = substr $s, 14, 7, "jumped from";    # climbed
    # $s is now "The black cat jumped from the green tree"
```

**Here is my code:**

```
    ...

    if($sheet->Range("B". $i)->{Value} =~ m/\"/)
    {
                    my $cell = $sheet->Range("B". $i)->{Value};
                    print $cell . "\n"; # Notebook 24"
                    my $ind = index($cell, '\"');
                    print $ind ."\n";   # -1                        
                    my $newval = substr($cell, $ind, 0, " Inches");
                    print $newval . "\n"; # (blank)
                    <STDIN>;
                    $sheet->Range("B". $i)->{Value} = $newval;                      
    }

    ...
```

**EDIT: (ADDED AN EXAMPLE OUTPUT IN THE CONSOLE)**
[image]

**EDIT 2: (INDEX IS NOW POSITIVE AND CORRECT)**

```
...

if($sheet->Range("B". $i)->{Value} =~ m/\"/)
{
                my $cell = $sheet->Range("B". $i)->{Value};
                print $cell . "\n"; # Notebook 24"
                my $ind = index($cell, '"');
                print $ind ."\n";  # 11                       
                my $newval = substr($cell, $ind, 0, " Inches");
                print $newval . "\n"; # (blank)
                <STDIN>;
                $sheet->Range("B". $i)->{Value} = $newval;                       
}

...
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: You probably intended `$sheet->Range("B". $i)->{Value} =~ s/"/Inches/;` instead $newval [substr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).

Comment: This is the solution! I will post the entire solution now.

Comment: You can remove whole your block and leave only command above, the replacement will take place only on presence of `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes don't need a backslash in single quotes.

```
index($cell, '\"');
```

On the contrary: it searches for a backslash followed by double quotes, which isn't present in the string, so the returned value is -1.

```
say index 'Notebook 24"', '\"';  # -1
say index 'Notebook 24"', '"';   # 11
```

Comment: You are right but it sadly didn't solve the problem. The index is now positive and correct but `$newval` is still blank. Why? I edited my OP.

Comment: You extracted a string of length 0 from $cell and assigned it to $newval, so it's empty. $cell has changed, though.

Comment: I thought I had to reassign the changes. Didn't know that Perl does this in-house out of the box...Thank you!

Comment: See [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) for the complete documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution:**

```
...

if($sheet->Range("B". $i)->{Value} =~ m/\"/)
{                   
   $sheet->Range("B". $i)->{Value} =~ s/"/ Inches/;                        
}

...
```

Comment: Note: `if` is not required -- replacement takes place only on presence of `"`.

Comment: Scope of data stored in the column is not known to readers, substitution takes place only on first occurrence of `"` (otherwise `s/"/ Inches/g` can be used). Assumed that the cell has some digital value followed by `"` as `2.62"` only.